Creating a new Next.js app gives `npm warn deprecated` messages for `inflight@1.0.6` and other packages
When I create a new Next.js app via npx create-next-app@latest ., I get the following messages
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

This does not stop me from using Next.js, but I've tried to add Sentry to an app via the CLI and the same messages pop up, particularly inflight@1.0.6. I've tried installing the recommended packages in the messages but no luck.
Below is the package.json file:
{
  "name": "cypress",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5"
  }
}

happy to upload any other info needed
I tried installing the packages recommended in the warning messages with no luck, and I've changed the eslint version in the package.json file, from: "eslint": "^8", to: "eslint": "^9" then running npm install, npm install --force and npm install --legacy-peer-deps with no luck.
EDIT: following this thread, I switched to yarn and no longer had the error, which is curious. If anyone can explain why that is I would be so grateful!!

Long story short, this is because the eslint version used by next.js is using archived library called inflight source
the temporary solution is to use overrides in package.json source
"overrides": {
"eslint": "^9",
"glob": "^10"
}

and remove "eslint": "^9" from devDependencies

eslint-config-next needs eslint@"^7.23.0 || ^8.0.0" from eslint-config-next@14.2.5.
So the solution is to remove eslint-config-next from package.json and upgrade eslint to "eslint": "^9.8.0"
It worked for me

The obvious downside to which is you lose eslint-config-next, which you want (I assume, given that you've set it up...)?

I tried the above, but now I'm getting the following error
(node:14280) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

